# what happen to my server, it crashed

Tags: centos

I have CentOS 6.2 64bit installed, it's been up for 44 days. It suddenly crashed, so I logged into KVM and check - I managed to print screen this.

![http://picpaste.com/1-cgYdKDAy.png 
(im new so not able to upload picture here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ff3D.png)

Any idea what could have caused that? I asked the data center to hard reboot the server now its ok again, I'm able to login to ssh. What log should I check?

**Update**

Here are the logs requested from /var/log/message:

```
Jun 28 12:24:27 la-noc lfd[13058]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:24:27 la-noc lfd[13058]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:25:55 la-noc proftpd[12732]: 96.44.184.123 (115.133.56.39[115.133.56.39]) - Client session idle timeout, disconnected
Jun 28 12:25:55 la-noc proftpd[12732]: 96.44.184.123 (115.133.56.39[115.133.56.39]) - FTP session closed.
Jun 28 12:26:28 la-noc lfd[13114]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:26:28 la-noc lfd[13114]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:26:42 la-noc lfd[13125]: DynDNS - update IP addresses
Jun 28 12:28:06 la-noc proftpd[13188]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session opened.
Jun 28 12:28:06 la-noc proftpd[13188]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session closed.
Jun 28 12:28:28 la-noc lfd[13204]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:28:28 la-noc lfd[13204]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:28:55 la-noc kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:e0:81:43:95:42:00:04:80:5c:17:25:08:00 SRC=79.169.210.214 DST=96.44.184.126 LEN=60 TOS=0x$
Jun 28 12:28:58 la-noc kernel: Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:e0:81:43:95:42:00:04:80:5c:17:25:08:00 SRC=79.169.210.214 DST=96.44.184.126 LEN=60 TOS=0x$
Jun 28 12:30:29 la-noc lfd[13291]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:30:29 la-noc lfd[13291]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:31:43 la-noc lfd[13332]: DynDNS - update IP addresses
Jun 28 12:32:29 la-noc lfd[13363]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:32:29 la-noc lfd[13363]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:34:02 la-noc proftpd[13415]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session opened.
Jun 28 12:34:02 la-noc proftpd[13415]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session closed.
Jun 28 12:34:29 la-noc lfd[13434]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:34:29 la-noc lfd[13434]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:36:29 la-noc lfd[13493]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:36:29 la-noc lfd[13493]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:36:44 la-noc lfd[13506]: DynDNS - update IP addresses
Jun 28 12:38:29 la-noc lfd[13555]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:38:29 la-noc lfd[13555]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:39:03 la-noc proftpd[13600]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session opened.
Jun 28 12:39:03 la-noc proftpd[13600]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session closed.
Jun 28 12:40:29 la-noc lfd[13648]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:40:29 la-noc lfd[13648]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:41:44 la-noc lfd[13680]: DynDNS - update IP addresses
Jun 28 12:42:29 la-noc lfd[13712]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:42:29 la-noc lfd[13712]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:44:29 la-noc lfd[13771]: cannot chdir to /etc/csf from /tmp/.wapi: Permission denied, aborting. at /usr/sbin/lfd line 4790.
Jun 28 12:44:29 la-noc lfd[13771]: daemon stopped
Jun 28 12:44:30 la-noc proftpd[13781]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session opened.
Jun 28 12:44:30 la-noc proftpd[13781]: 96.44.184.123 (127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]) - FTP session closed.
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: imklog 4.6.2, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="4.6.2" x-pid="1459" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] (re)start
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Linux version 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b5.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC) ) #1 S$
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Command line: ro root=/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root rd_NO_LUKS LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD rd_LVM_LV=VolGroup/lv_swap SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-s$
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  Intel GenuineIntel
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  AMD AuthenticAMD
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  Centaur CentaurHauls
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009f400 (usable)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 000000000009f400 - 00000000000a0000 (reserved)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000000e0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000fbff0000 (usable)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fbff0000 - 00000000fbfff000 (ACPI data)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000fbfff000 - 00000000fc000000 (ACPI NVS)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 00000000ff780000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000400000000 (usable)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: DMI 2.3 present.
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SMBIOS version 2.3 @ 0xF7570
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: AMI BIOS detected: BIOS may corrupt low RAM, working around it.
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: last_pfn = 0x400000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: x86 PAT enabled: cpu 0, old 0x7040600070406, new 0x7010600070106
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: total RAM covered: 16320M
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Found optimal setting for mtrr clean up
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: gran_size: 64K   chunk_size: 128M        num_reg: 4      lose cover RAM: 0G
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: last_pfn = 0xfbff0 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: init_memory_mapping: 0000000000000000-00000000fbff0000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: init_memory_mapping: 0000000100000000-0000000400000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: RAMDISK: 37217000 - 37fefcd2
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: RSDP 00000000000f6f20 00024 (v02 ACPIAM)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: XSDT 00000000fbff0100 00054 (v01 A M I  OEMXSDT  07000626 MSFT 00000097)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: FACP 00000000fbff0281 000F4 (v01 A M I  OEMFACP  07000626 MSFT 00000097)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: DSDT 00000000fbff0410 03751 (v01  0AAAA 0AAAA000 00000000 INTL 02002026)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: FACS 00000000fbfff000 00040
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: APIC 00000000fbff0380 00084 (v01 A M I  OEMAPIC  07000626 MSFT 00000097)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: OEMB 00000000fbfff040 00041 (v01 A M I  OEMBIOS  07000626 MSFT 00000097)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: SRAT 00000000fbff3b70 00110 (v01 A M I  OEMSRAT  07000626 MSFT 00000097)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: ACPI: ASF! 00000000fbff3cc0 00086 (v01 AMIASF AMDSTRET 00000001 INTL 02002026)
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 0 -> Node 0
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: PXM 0 -> APIC 1 -> Node 0
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 2 -> Node 1
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: PXM 1 -> APIC 3 -> Node 1
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 100000-fc000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: Node 1 PXM 1 200000000-400000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 100000000-200000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: SRAT: Node 0 PXM 0 0-9fc00
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: Bootmem setup node 0 0000000000000000-0000000200000000
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  NODE_DATA [0000000000028040 - 000000000005c03f]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  bootmap [000000000005d000 -  000000000009cfff] pages 40
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel: (9 early reservations) ==> bootmem [0000000000 - 0200000000]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  #0 [0000000000 - 0000001000]   BIOS data page ==> [0000000000 - 0000001000]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  #1 [0000006000 - 0000008000]       TRAMPOLINE ==> [0000006000 - 0000008000]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  #2 [0001000000 - 000200c864]    TEXT DATA BSS ==> [0001000000 - 000200c864]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  #3 [0037217000 - 0037fefcd2]          RAMDISK ==> [0037217000 - 0037fefcd2]
Jun 28 15:56:26 la-noc kernel:  #4 [000009f400 - 0000100000]    BIOS reserved ==> [000009f400 - 0000100000]
```

**Update**
sar output goes here:

```
root@la-noc [~]# sar
Linux 2.6.32-220.13.1.el6.x86_64 (server.abc.com)  06/28/2012      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      0.87      0.01      0.34      0.35      0.00     98.44
12:20:01 AM     all      0.51      0.01      0.25      0.18      0.00     99.04
12:30:01 AM     all      0.62      0.01      0.26      0.22      0.00     98.89
12:40:01 AM     all      0.78      0.01      0.31      0.27      0.00     98.63
12:50:01 AM     all      0.52      0.01      0.25      0.18      0.00     99.04
01:00:01 AM     all      0.71      0.01      0.25      0.22      0.00     98.81
01:10:01 AM     all      0.61      0.19      0.33      0.33      0.00     98.54
01:20:01 AM     all      0.51      0.01      0.24      0.19      0.00     99.05
01:30:01 AM     all      0.55      0.01      0.26      0.21      0.00     98.97
01:40:01 AM     all      0.56      0.01      0.31      0.21      0.00     98.92
01:50:01 AM     all      0.40      0.01      0.21      0.18      0.00     99.20
02:00:01 AM     all      0.55      0.01      0.25      0.23      0.00     98.96
02:10:01 AM     all      0.60      0.01      0.29      0.36      0.00     98.75
02:20:01 AM     all      0.66      0.01      0.24      0.19      0.00     98.91
02:30:01 AM     all      2.65      0.01      0.43      0.24      0.00     96.66
02:40:01 AM     all      1.90      0.01      0.54      0.26      0.00     97.29
02:50:01 AM     all      3.31      0.02      0.54      0.31      0.00     95.82
03:00:01 AM     all      1.48      0.01      0.33      0.27      0.00     97.91
03:10:01 AM     all      0.88      0.01      0.33      0.44      0.00     98.34
03:20:01 AM     all      0.62      0.19      0.40      0.24      0.00     98.54
03:30:01 AM     all      0.94      0.01      0.41      0.19      0.00     98.45
03:40:01 AM     all      1.17      0.01      0.35      0.21      0.00     98.26
03:50:01 AM     all      0.82      0.02      0.37      0.20      0.00     98.59
04:00:01 AM     all      0.61      0.01      0.30      0.18      0.00     98.91
04:10:01 AM     all      0.66      0.01      0.28      0.35      0.00     98.70
04:20:01 AM     all      0.37      0.01      0.23      0.17      0.00     99.22
04:30:01 AM     all      0.72      0.01      0.25      0.16      0.00     98.86
04:40:01 AM     all      0.83      0.02      0.29      0.18      0.00     98.69
04:50:01 AM     all      0.51      0.01      0.24      0.21      0.00     99.03
05:00:01 AM     all      0.63      0.01      0.25      0.22      0.00     98.89
05:10:01 AM     all      0.80      0.01      0.34      0.39      0.00     98.47
05:20:01 AM     all      0.56      0.19      0.26      0.22      0.00     98.77
05:30:01 AM     all      0.69      0.02      0.35      0.26      0.00     98.69
05:40:01 AM     all      0.79      0.01      0.51      0.24      0.00     98.45
05:50:01 AM     all      0.45      0.01      0.23      0.16      0.00     99.15
06:00:01 AM     all      0.52      0.01      0.26      0.21      0.00     98.99
06:10:01 AM     all      0.95      0.01      0.33      0.44      0.00     98.27
06:20:01 AM     all      0.79      0.02      0.30      0.24      0.00     98.65
06:30:01 AM     all      1.16      0.01      0.31      0.20      0.00     98.33
06:40:01 AM     all      0.70      0.01      0.29      0.23      0.00     98.77
06:50:01 AM     all      0.77      0.01      0.25      0.21      0.00     98.77
07:00:01 AM     all      0.76      0.01      0.27      0.26      0.00     98.70

07:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
07:10:01 AM     all      0.68      0.20      0.32      0.40      0.00     98.40
07:20:01 AM     all      1.03      0.01      0.37      0.21      0.00     98.38
07:30:01 AM     all      0.67      0.01      0.25      0.19      0.00     98.89
07:40:01 AM     all      0.77      0.01      0.31      0.25      0.00     98.66
07:50:01 AM     all      1.09      0.01      0.30      0.33      0.00     98.27
08:00:01 AM     all      1.27      0.02      0.36      0.23      0.00     98.13
08:10:01 AM     all      0.70      0.01      0.29      0.37      0.00     98.64
08:20:01 AM     all      0.54      0.01      0.24      0.19      0.00     99.03
08:30:01 AM     all      0.73      0.01      0.27      0.27      0.00     98.73
08:40:01 AM     all      0.67      0.01      0.28      0.27      0.00     98.77
08:50:01 AM     all      0.48      0.02      0.23      0.16      0.00     99.11
09:00:01 AM     all      0.52      0.01      0.24      0.21      0.00     99.02
09:10:01 AM     all      0.63      0.18      0.32      0.34      0.00     98.52
09:20:01 AM     all      0.86      0.01      0.31      0.23      0.00     98.60
09:30:01 AM     all      0.84      0.01      0.28      0.29      0.00     98.57
09:40:01 AM     all      1.36      0.02      0.34      0.27      0.00     98.01
09:50:01 AM     all      1.12      0.01      0.31      0.26      0.00     98.29
10:00:01 AM     all      0.49      0.01      0.25      0.20      0.00     99.05
10:10:01 AM     all      0.55      0.01      0.26      0.34      0.00     98.84
10:20:01 AM     all      0.61      0.01      0.27      0.23      0.00     98.89
10:30:01 AM     all      0.76      0.02      0.28      0.28      0.00     98.66
10:40:01 AM     all      0.60      0.01      0.30      0.25      0.00     98.84
10:50:01 AM     all      0.71      0.01      0.37      0.27      0.00     98.65
11:00:01 AM     all      0.58      0.01      0.35      0.25      0.00     98.81
11:10:01 AM     all      1.03      0.21      0.44      0.43      0.00     97.89
11:20:01 AM     all      0.74      0.02      0.27      0.26      0.00     98.72
11:30:01 AM     all      0.78      0.01      0.27      0.29      0.00     98.66
11:40:01 AM     all      0.79      0.01      0.29      0.20      0.00     98.70
11:50:01 AM     all      0.90      0.01      0.55      0.54      0.00     98.00
12:00:01 PM     all      0.84      0.01      0.53      0.73      0.00     97.89
12:10:01 PM     all      0.92      0.02      0.90      1.50      0.00     96.66
12:20:01 PM     all      0.87      0.01      0.87      1.44      0.00     96.81
12:30:01 PM     all      0.89      0.01      0.86      1.42      0.00     96.82
12:40:01 PM     all      0.88      0.01      0.86      1.31      0.00     96.93
Average:        all      0.82      0.02      0.34      0.32      0.00     98.49

03:56:19 PM       LINUX RESTART

04:00:01 PM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
04:10:01 PM     all      0.96      0.19      0.41      1.10      0.00     97.34
04:20:01 PM     all      0.47      0.01      0.22      0.30      0.00     99.00
04:30:01 PM     all      0.52      0.01      0.24      0.33      0.00     98.90
04:40:01 PM     all      0.88      0.02      0.33      0.65      0.00     98.12
04:50:01 PM     all      1.35      0.01      0.30      0.27      0.00     98.06
05:00:01 PM     all      0.66      0.01      0.26      0.26      0.00     98.82
05:10:01 PM     all      0.46      0.01      0.23      0.23      0.00     99.08
05:20:01 PM     all      0.51      0.01      0.22      0.23      0.00     99.03
05:30:01 PM     all      0.64      0.01      0.30      0.26      0.00     98.78
05:40:01 PM     all      0.73      0.01      0.29      0.41      0.00     98.56
05:50:01 PM     all      0.60      0.01      0.22      0.23      0.00     98.94
06:00:01 PM     all      0.61      0.01      0.35      0.26      0.00     98.78
06:10:01 PM     all      0.55      0.01      0.26      0.29      0.00     98.89
06:20:01 PM     all      0.67      0.21      0.27      0.31      0.00     98.55
06:30:01 PM     all      1.07      0.01      0.36      0.33      0.00     98.23
06:40:01 PM     all      0.95      0.01      0.51      0.39      0.00     98.14
06:50:01 PM     all      0.75      0.01      0.39      0.24      0.00     98.61
07:00:01 PM     all      0.84      0.01      0.50      0.23      0.00     98.43
Average:        all      0.73      0.03      0.31      0.35      0.00     98.57
root@la-noc [~]#
```

**update** i was uploading huge video files to my server using ftp with 1.1Mbps speed, is the hardisk failure caused the server to dead?

Comment: The front fell off.

Comment: This crash is in your Broadcom NIC driver. The first thing to do in these cases is to update the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's (the bottom of) the output from a kernel panic; the interesting bit will be at the top. Since the server's already been rebooted, your best bet will be to look for the error in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: these is the last few line before and after crashed: http://pastebin.com/rQxaXEVQ

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sysstat installed (the `sar` command)? If so, it can give you very useful historic information regarding server load, memory usage, disk IOPS, etc. It won't give you a definitive answer, but knowing what the server was doing prior to the kernel panic always helps.

If you don't have it installed, I'd install it for future use.

Comment: server crashed after 12:40:01 PM

Comment: @Redbox So? It keeps older logs too.

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons. Misbehaving hardware, misbehaving drivers, cooling so on and so forth. Without a complete stacktrace it is difficult to diagnose.

I'd say do check a few basic things --
* Keep your software (kernel included) up-to-date
* Ensure only linux compatible hardware is used
* Check your system/CPU temperature. Check if your RAID and HDD's are performing well with your raid controller utility
* Enable kernel core dump (google for instructions)
* If the server can be taken offline, run some stress tests -- bonnie++/fio/iozone and capture data via sar.

Cheers,
Chida